# React Navigation 5 - Nested navigation doesn't navigate

Tags: typescript, react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-v5

I have a bottom tab navigator with two nested stack navigators like this:

```
import React from "react";
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs";
import { createStackNavigator } from "@react-navigation/stack";
import { NavigatorScreenParams } from "@react-navigation/native";

type BottomTabParams = {
  ScreenA: undefined;
  ScreenB: NavigatorScreenParams<StackBParams>;
};

const BottomTab = createBottomTabNavigator<BottomTabParams>();
const BottomTabNavigator = () => {
  return (
    <BottomTab.Navigator initialRouteName="ScreenA">
      <BottomTab.Screen name="ScreenA" component={StackANavigator} />
      <BottomTab.Screen name="ScreenB" component={StackBNavigator} />
    </BottomTab.Navigator>
  );
};

export type StackAParams = {
  ScreenA: NavigatorScreenParams<BottomTabParams>;
  ScreenADetails: IADetailsData;
};

const StackA = createStackNavigator<StackAParams>();
const StackANavigator = () => {
  return (
    <StackA.Navigator screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }}>
      <StackA.Screen name="ScreenA" component={AScreen} />
      <StackA.Screen name="ScreenADetails" component={ADetailsScreen} />
    </StackA.Navigator>
  );
};

export type StackBParams = {
  ScreenB: undefined;
  ScreenBDetails: IBDetailsData;
};

const StackB = createStackNavigator<StackBParams>();
const StackBNavigator = () => {
  return (
    <StackB.Navigator screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }}>
      <StackB.Screen name="ScreenB" component={BScreen} />
      <StackB.Screen name="ScreenBDetails" component={BDetailsScreen} />
    </StackB.Navigator>
  );
};

export default BottomTabNavigator;
```

Now, in `ADetailsScreen` I want to navigate to `BDetailsScreen`, like this:

```
const ADetailsScreen: FunctionComponent<StackScreenProps<StackAParams, "ScreenADetails">> = ({
  navigation,
  route,
}) => {

  const onPress = () => {
     navigation.navigate("ScreenA", { 
       screen: "ScreenB", 
       params: { 
         screen: "ScreenBDetails", 
         params: detailsData 
       }
     });
  }

  return (...);
}
```

But, this is not working, I'm just navigated to `ScreenA`. What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE:**

My bottom tab navigation is also in a stack navigator:

```
const Stack = createStackNavigator<RootStackParams>();
const RootNavigator = () => {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }}>
      <Stack.Screen name="Root" component={BottomTabNavigator} />
      <Stack.Screen name="NotFound" component={NotFoundScreen} options={{ title: "Oops!" }} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
};
```

But, the following doesn't work either:

```
 navigation.navigate("ScreenA", { 
   screen: "Root", 
   params: { 
     screen: "ScreenB", 
     params: { 
       screen: "ScreenBDetails", 
       params: detailsData 
     }
   }
 });
```

Comment: There is no screen "ScreenB" under screenA right? you say navigate to screenB under ScreenA